# Calculate the integral of $f(x,y,z)=e^z$ over the tetrahedron with vertices $(4,0,0), (0,4,0), (0,0,6)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How does one setup this integral? Do I simply need an equation for the plane? I want to say this is the answer $\int_{0}^{6}\int_{0}^{4-z}\int_{0}^{4-y-z}(e^z)\space{dx}\space{dy}\space{dz}$ but something does not feel right.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest as the follows, but you better double check !!!

The plane equation is $$3x+3y+2z=12$$ 
Then, integration over the tetrahedron may be written as 
$$
\int_{T}f(x,y,z)dxdydz
=
\int_0^6\int_0^{\frac{12-2z}{3}}\int_0^{\frac{12-3y-2z}{3}}e^zdxdydz=\frac{4}{9} \left(e^6-25\right).
$$

Comment: how did you come up with plane equation?

Comment: When a plane has intercepts $a$ in $x$, $b$ in $y$, and $c$ in $z$,  then the plane equation is $\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}+\frac{z}{c}=1$.